# Add node_module bootstrap scss to gulp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, node-modules

I have installed bootstrap 4 beta using npm and I want to add it to my project. I have gulp and I want to have bootstrap's scss in it ... How can I do it ?

Comment: Just add the path of bootstrap to your gulp scss or you can include the bootstrap scss on your main scss file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have foundation. You should replace the path to bootstrap.

```
.pipe(sass({
    includePaths: ["./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"]
}).on("error", sass.logError))
```